# Telerik image editor Tool Dialog issue

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am trying to implement  a rad editor. In it there is an Image Manager and inside the image manager is an Image Editor. So far its fine(the image is being shown perfectly).

As in every story there is a villain here it is.

Now the problem arises when i click on any of the tool buttons in the image editor window. The popup screen but there is nothing inside it. Like when i click on the Crop button the popup heading is just Tool Dialog and there is no content in it. A preview can be seen [image: here].

This issue is arising only when i use it in a RadEditor. When i am using an Image Manager alone then there is no issue. I am kind of stuck here..

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a follow-up, because there is addition information on the issue. The problem is discussed in the following help article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radcompression.html

Known issues
Problem

When RadCompression is enabled and you are using .NET 4.0, event handlers might not be raised in a default document in IIS 7 or IIS 7.5 Integrated Mode.

Solution

This problem is caused by a breaking change in .NET 4.0 described here. To workaround it one can set preCondition="managedHandler" for the RadCompression module. You may also need to remove the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests setting from your web.config if you have it (or set it to false).

Answer (score 1):

I am aware of this problem which is caused by IIS of Windows 2008 server. The problem arise when the when the loaded URL in the browser doesn't contain the exact page hosting the control.

For example the control will not work at www.domain.com, but it will work at www.domain.com/Default.aspx.

Here you can find article, which discusses such a problem: http://forums.iis.net/p/1175925/1973069.aspx.

Please, note that the issue is not directly related to Telerik controls. If you are unable to solve it you could contact Microsoft or search in Internet for a solution.

Comment: i checked it up and it's not with the IIS. I checked up with the Telerik posts and then found that they are aware of this issue and that they are fixing it up in the next build or something. Take a look at this forum http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/image-editor/dynamic-load-problem.aspx

Comment: I think that these are two different problems. Is it possible to provide a live URL to the problematic page and tell us the name of the ASPX page?